# Adding jsoncpp external library to my qt project : (symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64)

Tags: c++, qt, linker, jsoncpp

I'm trying to add jasoncpp library to my C++ qt project.
I included the header, and linked (I think) the library but I get these errors: 
"symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" and "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)".

The symbols not found are obviously the ones concerning jsoncpp library.

This is my makefile:

```
QT       += core gui webkitwidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = JsonTest
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/0.5.0/lib/release/ -ljson
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/0.5.0/lib/debug/ -ljson
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/0.5.0/lib/ -ljson

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/0.5.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/0.5.0/include
```

I really don't know how to proceed so thanks in advance.

Comment: Double check to make sure you have the 64 bit version of the jsoncpp library and not the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it using cmake, try this commands:

```
mkdir -p build/debug
cd build/debug
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DJSONCPP_LIB_BUILD_STATIC=ON -DJSONCPP_LIB_BUILD_SHARED=OFF -G "Unix Makefiles" ../..
make
```

change

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/0.5.0/lib/release/ -ljson
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/0.5.0/lib/debug/ -ljson
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/0.5.0/lib/ -ljson

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/0.5.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/0.5.0/include
```

for this:

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -ljsoncpp
```

and ready to use jsoncpp